# Htaccess leaves root directory from path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have basedirectory abc for my sliframework.

Following Htaccess code has been written for it which i cant understand.

```
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
```

This excludes my root directory from the links.

Suppose project is in abc directory. I want my links like

http://localhost/abc/user/login

Instead I am getting

http://localhost/user/login

How can I include root directory into path ??